# Reading data points from a data file

Tags: java, algorithm, file-io, nearest-neighbor

I have a data file with 1000 data points that is organized like this:

```
1000
16   11
221   25
234   112
348   102
451   456
```

I'm trying to read the file into my program and find an arrangement of the points that results in the shortest total point to point distance. Since I have little experience with lists, I'm having a lot of trouble even reading the data points. Is there a better way to go about this? How do you run the list through a nearest neighbor algorithm?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("output.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    ArrayList<shortestRoute> arrayList = new ArrayList<shortestRoute>();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] fields = line.split("   ");

        arrayList.add(new shortestRoute(Integer.parseInt(fields[0]), Integer.parseInt(fields[1])));
    }
    scanner.close();

    System.out.println(arrayList);
}
```

I know that the formula for finding point to point distance is SquareRoot[(x2-x1)^2-(y2-y1)^2]. What I'm having trouble with is inputting the data points into the greedy algorithm.

Comment: safer to use .split("\\s+") which will skip any number of whitespace chars

Comment: What have you tried so far with the sorting? I don't see much of a problem in the way the data is read in. You probably want a null check in the arrayList.add function.

Comment: How do you calculate point to point distance? Is it just `mod(a-b)`?

Comment: It's probably more performance to use  a BufferedReader, and just as simple to read the data than use Scanner.

Comment: Try scanner.nextInt()

Comment: You also need to skip the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the first line is the number of points in the file.

Since it's all numbers just stick to using Scanner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("output.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    ArrayList<shortestRoute> arrayList = new ArrayList<shortestRoute>();

    for(int i =0, n = scanner.nextInt(); i < n; i++) {
        arrayList.add(new shortestRoute(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt()));
    }
    scanner.close();

    System.out.println(arrayList);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are splitting the input String using four spaces. Looking at the input file I assume that the numbers could also be separated by a tab. Rather using four spaces you should look for any white space. The split function should change like this:

```
String[] fields = line.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: You've got the right idea, but given that `nextLine` ensures that the line end is consumed, you don't run into weird `nextFoo` errors with the scanner not properly advancing.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Edited my response